# Ferry Ticketing Program Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment

I am required to come up with a program on booking tickets, I have already done the list for the seating arrangements which goes a little like this:

```
def SC1000():
     print(" ")
     print(" ")
     print("PURCHASING MODULE")
     print ("Your booking reference number is : ", bookingref)
     print("B - to purchase ticket for Business class")
     print("E - to purchase ticket for Economy class")
     print("M - to return to Main Menu")
     bore=input("Enter your choice : ")
     if (bore=="B"):
          seatingchoice = [[" ", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                           ["1" , "0" , "0" , "0" , "0" , "0"],
                           ["2" , "0" , "0" , "0" , "0" , "0"]]
          print("Seating Arrangement")
          print("Business Class")


          format_string="{:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4}"

          headers = seatingchoice [0]
          header_row = format_string.format(*headers)
          print(header_row)
          print("-" * len(header_row))


          for language in seatingchoice [1:3]:
              print(format_string.format(*language))


          sc=input("Enter your choice (eg:A3/a3): ")
          if sc in open('sc1000.txt').read():
              print("This seat has been taken, kindly choose another seat")
              SC1000()

          else:
             customersdata=[]
             name =input("Please enter your full name : ")
             cfile = open("sc1000.txt","a")
             cfile.write("\n")
             cfile.write(str(customersdata))
             cfile.close()

          #for line in cfile:
             if (sc=="A1") in open("sc1000.txt","r")():
                  seatingchoice[2][2]= 1
             elif (sc=="A2") in open("sc1000.txt","r")():
                  seatingchoice[3][2]= 1
             elif (sc=="B1") in open("sc1000.txt","r")():
                  seatingchoice[2][3]= 1
             elif (sc=="B2") in open("sc1000.txt","r")():
                  seatingchoice[3][3]= 1
             elif (sc=="C1") in open("sc1000.txt","r")():
                  seatingchoice[2][4]= 1




             customersdata.append(bookingref)
             customersdata.append(name)
             customersdata.append(sc)

             print("Boarding Ticket")
             print("____________________________________")
             print(" ")
             print("            Date:",time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
             print("             Time:",time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"))
             print(" Name          : ",name)
             print(" Ferry ID      : Ferry 1")
             print(" Boarding Time : 9.50am")
             print(" Departure     : Penang to Langkawi")
             print(" Seating Class : Business Class")
             print(" Seat Number   : ",sc)
             print(" Zone          : A")
             print(" Gate          : B1")
             print("_____________________________________")
             print(" ")
             print("Kindly print out the boarding pass as it will be needed at the gate.")
             gmm=input("When done printing, press 'D' to go back to the Main Menu. ")
             if (gmm=="D"):
                  mainmenu()
```

and it works, but I need to also store the data when the user keys in which seats they want, right now it is not saving the customers details into the txt file and I am sure theres something wrong with my codes, but I can not figure out what.

**ALSO** if anyone would like to share with me on how to change the 0 to 1 when the user chooses A1 for example, that would be really great!

Thank you for your help

Comment: Gotta go, ping me and I'll write my answer tomorrow (GMT).

Answer (score 1):

> right now it isnt saving the customers details into the txt file

Thats because you're writing an empty `customersdata` list:

```
 customersdata=[]
 name =input("Please enter your full name : ")
 cfile = open("sc1000.txt","a")
 cfile.write("\n")
 cfile.write(str(customersdata))
 cfile.close()
```

Comment: im still a little lost haha, this is my first time doing python & im only a year 1 IT student. is it ok for you to elaborate more?

Comment: `customersdata` starts out as an empty list, and you never add anything to it.  So, when you write `customersdata` to the file, you're writing an empty list.  I assume you intended to add `name` to the list, and possibly other things too, but you never actually do that.

Answer (score 0):

[@John Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51013882/9445557) is correct; you are currently writing an empty list to the file, then appending items to the list. To fix this, append the items to the list, **then** write it to the file. Here is the fixed code section of code:

```
      else:
         customersdata=[]
         name =input("Please enter your full name : ")

         if (sc=="A1") in open("sc1000.txt","r")():
              seatingchoice[2][2]= 1
         elif (sc=="A2") in open("sc1000.txt","r")():
              seatingchoice[3][2]= 1
         elif (sc=="B1") in open("sc1000.txt","r")():
              seatingchoice[2][3]= 1
         elif (sc=="B2") in open("sc1000.txt","r")():
              seatingchoice[3][3]= 1
         elif (sc=="C1") in open("sc1000.txt","r")():
              seatingchoice[2][4]= 1
         customersdata.append(bookingref)
         customersdata.append(name)
         customersdata.append(sc)
         cfile = open("sc1000.txt","a")
         cfile.write("\n")
         cfile.write(str(customersdata))
         cfile.close()
```

Comment: How does this fix anything?  `customersdata` is still an empty list.

Comment: Oh wait yeah one moment

Comment: Also, `if (sc=="A1") in open("sc1000.txt","r")():` is an error.  Perhaps you meant `if "A1" in open("sc1000.txt","r").read():`?

Comment: @JohnGordon This is copied from the OP's code. Just Look at it.